# Bulk insert of ICollection into an Oracle Table

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm writing an API client from a spec that came from Nswag studio.  I am able to retrieve that data using the supplied `client.PlansAsync(apikey).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but I'm struggling to turn the returned ICollection into something that I'm able to bulk insert into an Oracle database table.

I have attempted to create a `DataTable` but during the transformation into a dataTable, an exception is being thrown.  I'm suspect it has something to do with nullable types in the collection.

My guess is that I should be attempting to do the inserts using Entity Framework, but it seems like adding all of the extra EF Core stuff is overkill for this particular client.

I feel like the Oracle Bulk copy methods are perfect for what I'm intending, but I've been running to the issue listed above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

EDIT: Here's the code in question.

```cs
//first in the calling class
ICollection<Plans> plansFromApi = client_.PlansAsync(apiKey).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

ListToDatTable listToDt = new();
List<Plans> ps = plansFromApi.ToList();
DataTable dt = listToDt.ToDataTable<Plans>(ps);


//second the List to Datatable class

public class ListToDataTable
{
    public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new(typeof(T).Name);
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach(T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for(int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            //line where the exception is thrown
            //System.ArgumentException: 'Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.'
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
         }
     }
}
```

EDIT 2:
Here is what came out of Nswag studio. This is just one of 15 datasets that I need to retrieve.  This isn't the one I'm currently testing, as that one has 25 properties, so for brevity I'm including one of the smaller ones. In the end they all will be the same, since they are all going to be processed the exact same way, and yes, I have tested with this dataset as well, and received the same exception.

```cs
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.5.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class ContactGroupedManufacturer
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("lastContacted", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public System.DateTimeOffset? LastContacted { get; set; }
    
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("vendorContactId", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int VendorContactId { get; set; }
    
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("ManufacturerId", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("website", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Website { get; set; }
    
    
    }
```

Here area few rows of data:

| lastContacted | vendorContactId | manufacturerId | website |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6575 | 1848 |  |  |
| 6599 | 2693 |  |  |
| 6604 | 8878 | 06/08/2018 |  |
| 6692 | 6879 |  |  |
| 6930 | 4040 |  | some url |

---

UPDATE 2021/11/10: I found a NuGet package called [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq) that contained an extension method that handled the transformation to a `DataTable`.

```cs
ICollection<ActionPlans> actionPlans = client.ActionPlansAsync(apiKey).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
_logger.LogInformation(${actionPlans.Count} APs returned");

DataTable actionPlansDt = actionPlans.ToDataTable();
```

Comment: So where is the code, which does not work including the exception? Assume I left my guessing-pants are in the laundry.

Comment: @Marco I had a moment yesterday when I posted this, but I've added it.

Comment: We all have those from time to time.  Now please add the mentioned exception and where it occurs. Bonus points, if you can give a table schema and one or two rows of data to reproduce.

Comment: The exception happens on the statement ```dataTable.Rows.Add(values)```

Comment: The given exception is clear enough, you dont have enough columns in your data table. Check how many columns do you have, and how many properties you are trying to put into that table. You can also try to handle the creation process of columns in DataTable from properties by yourself, so you will be sure what properties you want to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have problem with quantity of columns in the DataTable.
Try this code:

```
public class ListToDataTable
{
    public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        bool columnsAlreadyCreated=false;
        foreach(T item in items)
        {
            if (columnsAlreadyCreated==false)
            {
              for(int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
              {
         dataTable.Columns.Add(Props[i].Name,Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(
         Props[i].PropertyType) ?? Props[i].PropertyType);
              }
              columnsAlreadyCreated=true;
            }
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for(int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            //line where the exception is thrown
            //System.ArgumentException: 'Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.'
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried modifying the code, but I'm still running into an issue with a ```nullable``` type.  When I get to a property that has ```System.Nullable...``` I get the exception ```Dataset does not support System.Nullable```

Comment: @RobM ok, thats another type of exception. I modified my code, changed lane which were adding columns to data source: `dataTable.Columns.Add(Props[i].Name,Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(
         Props[i].PropertyType) ?? Props[i].PropertyType);`
You should try it now.

Comment: @RobM you got that working ?

Comment: I ended finding a NuGet package called morelinq that had an extension method that created the database based on the `ICollection`.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the IEnumerable in a IDataReader to pass to the BulkCopy method.  See eg:
[ObjectDataReader](https://github.com/dbrownems/ObjectDataReader)

Once you have an IDataReader, pass it to `OracleBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader)` See [OracleBulkCopy](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleBulkCopyClass.htm#BIGEGECJ).

Comment: Will this work with Oracle? Looking at the code in the repo, it appears to be for SQL Server.

Comment: Yes OracleBulkCopy works just like SqlBulkCopy.  See updated answer.